# Scraping user ratings of Hunger Games using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape all the user ratings (out of 5) for the first book of Hunger Games Trilogy from goodreads.com. The biggest challenge is there are multiple pages of reviews but the link doesn't change when another page of comments are displayed. That's why I am using Selenium in order to navigate when looking for a new group of ratings.

Below you can see my code:

```
# initiating the chromedriver
path_to_chromedriver = r'./chromedriver.exe'

#launch url
url = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2767052-the-hunger-games"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

# initiating the beautifulsoup
soup_1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# finding the table that includes all the book reviews
user = soup_1.find('div', {'id': 'bookReviews'})

# finding all the individual ratings from that table
user = user.find_all('div',{'class':'friendReviews elementListBrown'})

# locating the next button on the page which is indicated with 'next »'
elm = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('next »')


for i in range(9): # since there are 10 pages of reviews

    for row in user: # finding for each separate rating

        rating = {}
        try: # try and except is needed because not all the users have a rating
            rating['name'] = row.find('a',{'class': 'user'}).text # grabbing the username
            rating['rating'] = row.find('span',{'class':'staticStars'})['title'] # grabbing user rating out of 5

            ratings.append(rating)

        except:

            pass


    elm.click() # clicking on the next button to scrape the other page

df_rev = pd.DataFrame(ratings) # merging all the results to build a data frame
df_rev
```

In the end, I want to get every user that rated and their ratings. Instead of having that, I end up with a data frame that has users and their ratings only from the first page of ratings duplicated many times starting from the first user until the last user on the first page.

The outcome:

```
name    rating
0   Kiki    liked it
1   Saniya  it was amazing
2   Khanh   it was amazing
3   Dija    it was amazing
4   Nataliya    really liked it
5   Jana    did not like it
6   Cecily  it was ok
7   Kiki    liked it
8   Saniya  it was amazing
9   Khanh   it was amazing
10  Dija    it was amazing
11  Nataliya    really liked it
12  Jana    did not like it
13  Cecily  it was ok
14  Kiki    liked it
15  Saniya  it was amazing
16  Khanh   it was amazing
17  Dija    it was amazing
18  Nataliya    really liked it
19  Jana    did not like it
20  Cecily  it was ok
21  Kiki    liked it
22  Saniya  it was amazing
23  Khanh   it was amazing
24  Dija    it was amazing
25  Nataliya    really liked it
26  Jana    did not like it
27  Cecily  it was ok
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from what I can see you haven't even initialized `ratings`.

But, I made some small changes, and it seems to be working. There are some structural things I'd change about your code. Well, a lot actually. But I guess it's not needed for your answer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit as pdf
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driveletter = os.getcwd().split(':')[0]

options = Options()
options.binary_location = driveletter+":\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe"
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=driveletter+":\PortableApps\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chromedriver.exe", )

#launch url
url = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2767052-the-hunger-games"

# create a new Chrome session
driver.get(url)

ratings = list()

last_page_source = ''

while True:
    page_changed = False # It's useful to declare whether the page has changed or not
    attempts = 0
    while(not page_changed):
        if last_page_source != driver.page_source:
            page_changed = True
        else:
            if attempts > 5: # Decide on some point when you want to give up.
                break;
            else:
                time.sleep(3) # Give time to load new page. Interval could be shorter.
                attempts += 1
    if page_changed:
        soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        user = soup_1.find('div', {'id': 'bookReviews'})
        user = user.find_all('div',{'class':'friendReviews elementListBrown'})

        for row in user: # finding for each separate rating

            rating = {}
            try:
                # try and except is needed because not all the users have a rating
                rating['name'] = row.find('a',{'class': 'user'}).text # grabbing the username
                rating['rating'] = row.find('span',{'class':'staticStars'})['title'] # grabbing user rating out of 5
                ratings.append(rating)

            except:
                pass
        last_page_source = driver.page_source
        next_page_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next_page')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page_element) # clicking on the next button to scrape the other page
    else:
        df_rev = pd.DataFrame(ratings) # merging all the results to build a data frame
        print(df_rev.drop_duplicates())
        break;
```

Output:

```
                                            name           rating
0                                           Kiki         liked it
1                                         Saniya   it was amazing
2    Khanh, first of her name, mother of bunnies   it was amazing
3                                           Dija   it was amazing
4                                       Nataliya  really liked it
5                                           Jana  did not like it
6                                         Cecily        it was ok
7                                Meredith Holley   it was amazing
8                                         Jayson  really liked it
9                               Chelsea Humphrey  really liked it
10                                 Miranda Reads  really liked it
11                                       ~Poppy~  really liked it
12                                        elissa   it was amazing
13                               Colleen Venable  really liked it
14                                         Betsy   it was amazing
15                                     Emily May  really liked it
16                                       Lyndsey   it was amazing
17                                      Morgan F   it was amazing
18                                    Huda Yahya         liked it
19                                Nilesh Kashyap        it was ok
20                                         Buggy   it was amazing
21                                         Tessa         liked it
22                                         Jamie   it was amazing
23                                 Richard Derus  did not like it
24                             Maggie Stiefvater   it was amazing
25                                         karen   it was amazing
26                                         James   it was amazing
27                                           Kai   it was amazing
28                                        Brandi  did not like it
29                                   Will Byrnes         liked it
..                                           ...              ...
263                                       shre ♡   it was amazing
264                                        Diane  really liked it
265                               Margaret Stohl   it was amazing
266                           Athena Shardbearer   it was amazing
267                                       Ashley         liked it
268                                Geo Marcovici   it was amazing
269                                        Pinky   it was amazing
270                                       Mariel  really liked it
271                                          Jim         liked it
272                                  Frannie Pan   it was amazing
273                                        Zanna  really liked it
274                                      Χαρά Ζ.  really liked it
275                     Anzu The Great Destroyer  really liked it
276                                         Beth   it was amazing
277                                        Karla  really liked it
278                                        Carla  did not like it
279                                       Shawna   it was amazing
280                             Susane Colasanti   it was amazing
281                                       Cherie  really liked it
283                                David Firmage         liked it
284                                       Farith   it was amazing
285                              Tony DiTerlizzi   it was amazing
286                                      Christy   it was amazing
287                                      Emerald   it was amazing
288                                       Sandra   it was amazing
289                           Chiara Pagliochini  really liked it
290                                       Argona   it was amazing
291                                      NZLisaM   it was amazing
292                                       Vinaya   it was amazing
293                                    Mac  Ross   it was amazing

[292 rows x 2 columns]
```

Explanation: You initialized you beautifulsoup based on the source-page of the initial link. You never changed this along with the clicks you made to change this source-page.

Edit: Had to make som changes as I had made mistakes in my original reply.

Comment: The `for i in range(n)` isn't needed either, by the way. I've already hinted as to how you can switch it out.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. Your output seems like working well but mine duplicates the first page almost 7 times and then scrapes the second page and creates the 'df_rev'. When I do 'df_rev.drop_duplicates()', there are only 58 rows. Couldn't understand the reason. Working on it!

Comment: Looking over it, the output I've gotten only includes up to page three. And there are a lot of duplicates in there. But the reason is simple: There's no delay or mechanism in your script to ensure that the new page has loaded before you collect your data. In short, you should ensure that the page_source does change when hitting next_page, and allow it time to do so.

Comment: I have now updated the code to account for this. Be aware that I have not used best practices though. But it does work, however. You may disregard that I set up my chromedriver differently from yours. It is done that way since I launch it from a USB-stick.